# Rhadoop with Elasticsearch-hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, rhadoop

I am using `hadoop` with a database from `ElasticSearch` (no hdfs).
Do you know if `elasticsearch-hadoop` can work together?
Else do you know how using analytics for my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a connector for Elasticsearch and Hadoop that is built and released by Elasticsearch:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/index.html

They just released the GA version 2.0 - here's the blog post about it:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/es-hadoop-2-0-g/